# Adding to elements to an array after a certain character javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, append

I am writing a program for a bowling game and want to add 0 after every 10 in my array. e.g

```
arr=[1,2,4,10,9,2,10,1,1];
```

this is what I want:

```
newarr=[1,2,4,10,0,9,2,10,0,1,1];
```

I have been trying:

```
for (i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
    if (arr[i]=10){
        newarr=arr.splice(i,0,0);
    }
}
console.log(newarr);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the way, you should use `==` for comparison.

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 4, 10, 9, 2, 10, 1, 1];
var newArr = new Array();

for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  newArr.push(arr[i]);
  if (arr[i] == 10) newArr.push(0);
}
alert(newArr);
```

Answer (score 3):

There are a few problems with your code.

- You are accidentally using `=` instead of `==`. The former is for assignment and the latter for comparison.
- [`Array.splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) modifies the original array, so there is no need for a new array.
- You should be inserting the `0` at position `i+1` instead of `i` to add it *after* the `10` instead of before.

```js
arr=[1,2,4,10,9,2,10,1,1];
for (i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
    if (arr[i]==10){
        arr.splice(i+1,0,0);
    }
}
console.log(arr);
```